# Creating patch branch from tag and merge that with trunk

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

Now we perform work in **branches**. These are merged down into **trunk** and killed when the features in them are done. So the **trunk** always contains the latest stable code.

When trunk is ready for a release a **tag** is created from **trunk** at that given point.
Now, how do we best handle the situation where we need to create a patch for a previous release?

We have a **tag** marking that release. But trunk now contains much more new features.
If we create a **branch** from the old **tag** how do we cleanly get the patch fixes into our **trunk** and also mark the new patch release with a new **tag**?

Can I **tag** the **branch** created from the initial **release tag** and **reintegrate merge** the **branch** with our **trunk**? Or will that pose a problem? I feel it might confuse Subversion.

This "picture" tries to illustrate the flow.

```
Work branches /-- itter. 1.0 --\      /- 2.0 -\           /------ 3.0 ----------\
             /                  \    /         \         /                   /   \
    ------------trunk----------------------------------------------------------------------  
                                  |                | v2.0 tag              /      | v3.0 tag  
                                  |                                       /
                                  | V1.0 tag----------\                  /
                                                       \-- Branch 1.1 --/
                                                                        |
                                                                        | V1.1 tag
```

Note that even though tags and branches are on the same lines here they actually reside in the standard **trunk, branches, tags** folder layout.

Note: the work branches does NOT have to have anything to do with a given release. I just named them 1.0 etc. But they could be named *foo*, *bar* or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have now been using the approach of tagging releases from trunk and going back creating a branch from that tag if a patch is needed for a time and it has been working fine with both single and multiple teams.

Answer (score 2):

The more common way is to keep the release branches (1.x, 2.x, ...) open and tag specific releases from there.

Only close the branches when you stop supporting that version.

```
        1.0     1.1         2.0     2.1         (release tags)
       /       /           /       /
   /----------- 1.x       /----------- 2.x      (release branches)
  /                      / 
----------------------------------------------- trunk
```

It is safe to merge fixes from a such a release branch to trunk, regardless of where this branch was branched off from (trunk, tag, or other branch).

Comment: I would also say that if you do regular merges, you might find that a distributed version control system (e.g. git or mercurial) is preferred over Subversion.

Comment: What if the branches named 1.0, 2.0 etc weren't contained releases though? What if they were sprint branches or even feature branches within sprint branches. The idea is to not have "logic" in the branches dictating what is a release. This is decided by the product owner and at any given time a release is made from the trunk. There could be 1, 10 or 0 ongoing branches at that time that don't have anything merged into trunk yet. That's why we tag the point on our trunk when a release is made from it. Only question is how to best go back and patch that type of tagged release.

Comment: If you have to manage several versions of your application in parallel (2.1, 3.0, ...) you can't rely just on trunk for releasing. Release branches are needed.

Comment: @inquam: feature branches exist when they're worked on. When their functionality is ready for release, you merge them to trunk and close them.  Then that state is branched off for release.

Comment: But since a patch is work being done on the trunk as it was a long time ago you can not merge it into trunk and then branch a release from that (i.e. tag). If so you would get all of the changes made and commited to trunk after the release of the version being patched as part of the path. The release has to be made BEFORE the changes are merged back into trunk. As stated, we use the "stable trunk" pattern. But the branches/tags could be named anything since it's all the same to subversion.

Comment: @antispam: As you see in my "picture" we tag our releases (which is the same as creating a branch at that point. For the v1.1 patch release you can see that this is NOT done from trunk but rather from the patch branch crated to make the patch release. Only "stable" planned releases are made from trunk.